# How to remove a field from each object of a list of object?

Tags: java, spring

I have a class **FilterEvent** with following attributes

```
filterId
filterValue
filterType
```

Suppose i have a list of `FilterEvent` called `filterEvents`.

I need to remove filterId from each of the object of the list .

I tried in following way

```
Set<FilterEvent> filterEvents = preparation.getFilterEvents();
filterEvents.stream().map(f->f.setFilterId(null))
```

to set filterId field set to null . This will not work since my filterId field is of type int .

I need either **filterId** set to **null** or need to remove the field itself.

Comment: Java is not Python. You can't do that. You can set a flag value, though, as you were trying to do with null. Perhaps -1?

Comment: You simply can't do this. The fields in an object cannot be removed and you can't set a field of type `int` to `null`. You need to redefine it as `Integer`.

Comment: You can change type of `filterId` to `Integer` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` won't work, since it's an intermediate operation, so it won't be executed unless it is followed by some terminal operation.

Use `forEach`:

```
Set<FilterEvent> filterEvents = preparation.getFilterEvents();
filterEvents.forEach(f->f.setFilterId(null));
```

However, if `setFilterId` expects an `int`, you can't pass `null`. You'll have to set it to some other value (0?).

Answer (score 2):

`int` is a primitive type so if you want to set `null` then change its data type from `int` to `Integer` and

```
filterEvents.stream().forEach(f->f.setFilterId(null));
```

or if you don't want to change the data type then set its default value i.e 0 or -1.

Answer (score 2):

Java constraint is that primitive integer can't be null.

Your problem does not lie in your wrong stream mapping. It is in the int property type of your **FilterEvent** class. Java constraint is that primitive types (int, long, boolean ...) can't be null.

You have 2 options:

- Either you change the **filterId** property of **FilterEvent** class to Integer type which as object can be referenced/set to *null*.
- Or set the *0* instead of *null* in **f.setFilterId(null)**.

btw. You should collect the stream or use forEach.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove a field from an object. The `FilterEvent` class represents an object that has those three fields. Therefore an object without a `filterId` field is not a `FilterEvent` object. You could make another class that represents a cut-down version of `FilterEvent`; let's call it `FilterEventValueAndType`. Then, with the relevant constructors and getters, you could do this:

```
Set<FilterEvent> filterEvents = preparation.getFilterEvents();
Set<FilterEventValueAndType> fevat = filterEvents.stream()
        .map(f->new FilterEventValueAndType(f))
        .collect(toSet());
```